# QGIS Reproject Tool doesn't change vector size?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, vector

I'm new to GIS and confused about the Reproject tool in QGIS.

I created a square vector grid in QGIS, with 100 4km by 4km cells. The grid was created in EPSG:3857 - WSG 84 / Pseudo-Mercator. But when using the ellipsoidal measurement tool, the grid cell dimensions didn't appear to be truly 4km x 4km, but instead closer to 3.9km x 3.9km. I realized I should have the grid projection be in a more specific projection to the region, so used the "Reproject" tool to project it to a UTM projection. This shifted the grid slightly (about one meter left).

However, when I made a new grid using the vector tool, and specified the regionally specific UTM CRS, the grids are slightly larger (not just shifted), and the measurement tool shows that the grid cells are in fact much closer to 4km x 4km, not 3.9.

Does this mean it is more accurate to create vectors when you specify the CRS to begin with?

Why doesn't the Reproject tool make the grid larger and match the requested dimensions for the grid 4km x 4km?

Is there a way to reproject where the size of the vector is corrected too, not just the placement?

I think I may be confused about how Reprojection actually works.

Comment: Using EPSG:3857 - WSG 84 / Pseudo-Mercator was the error as it's highly distorting distance the farther you  are from the equator. You should start again creating your grid in a suitable CRS for your area

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes, I do realize now that EPSG:3857 - WSG 84 / Pseudo-Mercator is distorting. I'm just confused why Reprojecting to a more suitable CRS doesn't change the dimensions of the grid, and just shifts it slightly. Whereas create a new grid in the new CRS does make the grid size larger.

Answer (score 1):

Because the distances in web Mercator were already distorted compared to ellipsoid/geodesic-based measurements. Reprojecting data doesn't make it more accurate. The 3.9 km (in geodesic distances) will still be approximately 3.9 km in a new coordinate system.

When you built the features in a local UTM zone, the projected distances are closer to the geodesic distances because UTM has less distance distortion versus distances on the underlaying ellipsoid.